# Do you have any idea for dynamic proxy server written in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy, same-origin-policy

I want to bypass HTTP same origin policy
by using dynamic proxy server written in nodejs

```
example)
http://proxy-domain.com/http://target-domain.com/api
browser -> proxy-domain.com -> target-domain.com/api
        <-*1                <-
*1 : Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

do you have any idea or sample code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` header, looks like you're talking about a CORS proxy. There are open source Node.js CORS proxies that you can look at for examples of how to do this. The best known is probably [corsproxy](https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy). The (pardon the pun) core of it is very compact:

```
module.exports = function addCorsHeaders (request, reply) {
  var allowedHeaders = [
    'authorization',
    'content-length',
    'content-type',
    'if-match',
    'if-none-match',
    'origin',
    'x-requested-with'
  ]

  function addAllowedHeaders (arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (allowedHeaders.indexOf(arr[i].trim().toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        allowedHeaders.push(arr[i].trim().toLowerCase())
      }
    }
  }
  addAllowedHeaders(Object.keys(request.headers))

  // depending on whether we have a boom or not,
  // headers need to be set differently.
  var response = request.response.isBoom ? request.response.output : request.response

  if (request.method === 'options') {
    response.statusCode = 200
    if (request.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
      addAllowedHeaders(
        request.headers['access-control-request-headers'].split(',')
      )
    }
  }

  response.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = request.headers.origin
  response.headers['access-control-allow-headers'] = allowedHeaders.join(', ')
  response.headers['access-control-expose-headers'] = 'content-type, content-length, etag'
  response.headers['access-control-allow-methods'] = 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE'
  response.headers['access-control-allow-credentials'] = 'true'

  reply.continue()
}
```